# Number of installations statistics for PyPI packages?

Tags: python, pypi

I've got a couple of packages on the Python Package Index (PyPI) now. Is there any way to get hold of statistics as to how many times they have been downloaded (either manually or via `easy_install` or `pip`?

Or, alternatively, how many views the main package page has received?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE 2: it's back!  There's now a "Downloads (All Versions)" just after the list of downloads (below the user-supplied docs).**

announcement at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2013-June/021344.html - it's currently daily counts; weeks and months will be added as they become available.  but, curiously, no total.

<strike>**UPDATE: this no longer works (the info is not displayed) - see http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2013-May/020855.html (unfortunately this affects the other answer too).**</strike>

maybe i'm misunderstanding (sorry) but i think this is on the pypi main page for your project!

see updates above for latest details (i've deleted info below that's no longer correct).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that! Doh! Do you happen to know if that includes downloads when it was installed via `pip install xxx`?

Comment: i don't know for sure, but i would guess so - that seems to just use http to grab things.

Comment: Maybe I'm just being dumb, but I don't see the "# downloads" column at all when I look at that page...

Comment: see the UPDATE i added 4 hours before your comment?

Comment: Aha! So *that's* the "this" that no longer works. I don't know whether to feel more or less dumb, now ;)

Comment: I could not found the "Downloads (All Versions)" (7.7.21). I only found:

View statistics for this project via Libraries.io, or by using our public dataset on Google BigQuery

for example: https://pypi.org/project/numpy/

Answer (score 26):

There are at least two packages that help with this: [`pypstats`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypstats/) and [`vanity`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vanity).  Vanity is very easy to use from the command line:

```
vanity numpy
```

and you'll get a printout to your console.

Comment: how to send this output to file?

Comment: vanity does not work anymore.https://github.com/aclark4life/vanity/issues/66

Answer (score 18):

I have tried the different methods in the other answers. As far as I am concerned, vanity does not work anymore, the reason is [here](https://github.com/aclark4life/vanity/issues/66/). Pip statistics are not available on pypi.python.org website, the reason is mention in [the Python Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/analyzing-pypi-package-downloads/) together with a detailed guide on how you can analyze PyPI download using Google Big Query (summarized below in this answer).

There are 2 methods which are still available.

### PyPIstats.org

**First method is easier than the second one** but seems less reliable as it sometimes returns `429 RATE LIMIT EXCEEDED`

1. Go to [pypistats.org](https://pypistats.org/);
2. search the package name;
3. get the statistics of its download. The following figure is the results of `numpy`. [image]

### Google Big Query

**Second method** is Google Big Query, recommended by PiPy [officially](https://packaging.python.org/guides/analyzing-pypi-package-downloads/).

1. Go to  https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/the-psf:pypi
2. Copy the following code into the `editor` window.

```
SELECT
  details.installer.name,
  COUNT(*) as download_count,
FROM `the-psf.pypi.downloads*`
WHERE
file.project = 'dvc'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX
BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE('2020-01-04'))
AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE('2020-02-04'))
GROUP BY details.installer.name
```

3. Click `run` button, get the results. The following 2 figures show the code and results of `numpy`.
   [image: code]  [image: results]

Please noter that the second method requires you have a google cloud account, **and** require you to provide your credict card information, **and** has limited query times every day. **So I personally recommend the first method.**

Comment: Note that pypistats.org seems to offer download statistics from the last six months only.

Comment: Note also that Google's BigQuery is available without credit card in [some cases](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/query-without-a-credit-card-introducing-bigquery-sandbox).

Comment: Clicking https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/the-psf:pypi lands me in "Now viewing project 'Valuable-YouTube-Video-Finder' in organisation 'No organisation'".

Answer (score 12):

https://pepy.tech/ will show information on the number of downloads and trends over time.

[image]

Comment: Finally a site that works, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Pip statistics is not available on pypi.python.org website and `vanity` package does not work as well.

Today you can get pip statistics only through this dataset in BigQuery: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/the-psf:pypi

Query example for https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dvc package:

```
SELECT
  details.system.name,
  COUNT(*) as download_count,
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
    [the-psf:pypi.downloads],
    DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -31, "day"),
    DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day")
  )
WHERE
  file.project = 'dvc'
GROUP BY details.system.name
```

Please note, some of the download signals are generated by monitoring tools and should not be counted as user's downloads. For example, you should exclude `null` values from the output:

```
Row details_system_name download_count   
1   Darwin  1111     
2   null    10000    
3   Windows 222  
4   Linux   3333
```

Comment: The link you provide doesn't seem to work anymore (unable to find dataset error).

Comment: I've just checked - it seems to work. You need to click "Compose Query" and copy\paste the select statement from the above.

Comment: It only works if you are currently a Google BigQuery customer, with an account that has been verified by providing your card details. The service is however free - you are not charged.

Comment: I cant believe how hard it is to obtain such simple statistic, thanks for the answer, this was the only thing that worked

Comment: This answer is so useful that it should be marked as Protected for the community

Comment: These downloads can be further filtered with `details.installer.name` to ignore downloads by [bandersnatch](https://github.com/pypa/bandersnatch), which is a mirroring tool.

Comment: The Big Query link seems not work anymore. Waring: "The Classic UI has been decomissioned as of October 1st. Go to Google Cloud Console". After I enter the Google Cloud Console, the code above does not works. Error: "Table-valued function not found: TABLE_DATE_RANGE at [5:3]"

Comment: Seconding @JingnanJia here. Same observation.l

Answer (score 2):

There is a site which I found: https://pypistats.org/packages/py3-pinterest

They track downloads but only for 1 day, 1 week and 1 month. @Dmitry Petrov's answer is better though.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the [pypistats](https://pypistats.org) website to check your statistics.

For the `pytest` package: https://pypistats.org/packages/pytest

The figures are coherent with the bigquery's ones. For instance for day `13-04`: 501685 downloads without mirror.

Using request :

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS num_downloads,
  SUBSTR(_TABLE_SUFFIX, 7, 8) AS `day`
FROM `the-psf.pypi.downloads*`
WHERE file.project = 'pytest'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX
    BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE(
      '%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
    AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day`
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this website for statistics - https://pypistats.org/

if you want to use it in a script you can use the api -

[https://pypistats.org/api/packages/{package_name}/recent](https://pypistats.org/api/packages/%7Bpackage_name%7D/recent)

Comment: I get a 404 when going to https://pypistats.org/search/

Comment: check now @joelostblom

Comment: Great, it works now (without `/search`)! And the information at https://pypistats.org/packages/session-info seems similar to what I posted in my answer about https://pepy.tech so they seem to be pulling from the same source.

Comment: its the same website so make scenes :) @joelostblom

Answer (score 1):

If you like to filter the data and check all downloads per installer run:

```
SELECT
  details.installer.name,
  COUNT(*) as download_count,
FROM `the-psf.pypi.downloads*`
WHERE
file.project = 'dvc'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX
BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE('2020-01-04'))
AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE('2020-02-04'))
GROUP BY details.installer.name
```

So you should see all the installers for e.g:
[image]

For more information check [useful-queries](https://packaging.python.org/guides/analyzing-pypi-package-downloads/#useful-queries)

Answer (score 1):

I came across https://www.piwheels.org which shows how many downloads a PyPi library has had. Just add the library you are checking to the end of this url e.g. numpy

https://www.piwheels.org/project/numpy/

[image]