# Download stats of pypi package: how to filter for real users?

Tags: python, pypi

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43817169/4126114) answer shows how to query the pypi public dataset on BigQuery for download statistics of a package. Breaking down results by `details.installer.name`, I see the following values for downloads of one of my packages: requests, pip, null, bandersnatch, Browser.

I understand that bandersnatch is a mirroring tool, so its counts shouldn't contribute to the "real user" stat that I'm after for my own package.

What about Browser and requests? Are these real users?

Here's a link to the query that I'm running: [git-remote-aws pypi downloads](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/savedquery/782177472620:0ef92a949fb84d60a7cfa6a569e75bf6)

Comment: Not really an answer, but some reading on the topic: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5499

Answer (score 2):

Basically: it's hard to tell, and it depends on what you consider a "real user". Is a `pip install` from a CI system a "real user"? This download would be indistinguishable from a `pip install` typed on a local machine.

This is also why PyPI doesn't display download statistics. See the caveats listed here: https://packaging.python.org/guides/analyzing-pypi-package-downloads/

Comment: I read that CI installations are actually distinguishable by an environment variable. Do you have a reference that shows if the "pip" installations include CI or not?

Comment: If they are (and that would vary from one CI to another), environment variables are not included in the metadata that `pip` sends to PyPI which is recorded.